# Error at visualization of mnist NN with keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, mnist, graph-visualization

I installed anaconda and all the packages I needed. I tried to run this [mnist example from keras](https://keras.io/datasets/#mnist-database-of-handwritten-digits) It works fine. Now I'm trying to visualize the Graph with [keras manual](https://keras.io/visualization/). but it does not work.

When I run the mnist example I receive this error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dummy.py", line 77, in <module>
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 132, in plot_model
    dot = model_to_dot(model, show_shapes, show_layer_names, rankdir)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 55, in model_to_dot
    _check_pydot()
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 26, in _check_pydot
    pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1885, in create
    assert p.returncode == 0, p.returncode
AssertionError: 1
```

I also tried the [convnet_drawer](https://github.com/yu4u/convnet-drawer). It failed too.

Any Ideas?

Comment: do you have graphviz installed? That's where the dot utility comes from.

Comment: Yes, its installed. Thanks for your reply

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: per "conda install graphviz"

Comment: have you tried to import it in the python console?

Comment: Thanks to you!Problem solved. Maybe my enddevice was too old. I installed everything again on a new notebook. This time I used this manual -> https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/The-Best-Way-to-Install-TensorFlow-with-GPU-Support-on-Windows-10-Without-Installing-CUDA-1187/